# Independent barplots on same scale in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am evaluating the effect of changing various settings in an experiment on the measured outcome.  In particular, I have 3 settings, each of which has a different number of options, and none of the options are the same.  However, I'd like to plot the outcome over all the settings in a single plot.

More concretely, the data looks like:

```
Setting Option Value
Grp1    O1_1   0.2
Grp1    O1_2   0.6
Grp1    O1_3   0.5
Grp2    O2_1   0.4
Grp2    O2_2   0.6
Grp2    O2_3   0.7
Grp2    O2_4   0.3
Grp3    O3_1   0.9
Grp3    O3_2   0.6
```

And I'd like to produce a plot that looks something like this (the mockup does not reflect the numbers given above):
[image: multiple independent bar graphs on same scale]

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
library(ggplot2)

read.table(text="Setting Option Value
Grp1    O1_1   0.2
Grp1    O1_2   0.6
Grp1    O1_3   0.5
Grp2    O2_1   0.4
Grp2    O2_2   0.6
Grp2    O2_3   0.7
Grp2    O2_4   0.3
Grp3    O3_1   0.9
Grp3    O3_2   0.6", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

ggplot(df, aes(Option, Value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=Option, yend=0), size=15, color="#b5b5b5") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=c(0, 1), labels=c("0.0", "1.0"), limits=c(0, 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~Setting, nrow=1, scales="free_x", strip.position="bottom") +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line.y=element_line())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  `facet_wrap` is exactly what I needed.